# How to get GUID of an asset from FQDN using Purview API

Tags: api, azure-powershell, azure-purview

I am using Purview from a very long time. Now I am trying to automate few things using Purview API and Powershell.

So the current task which I am doing is, get GUID of an asset using FQDN as an input. Below is the API doc from Microsoft which I found during my research.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/purview/catalogdataplane/entity/get-by-unique-attributes?tabs=HTTP

Can anyone tell me how to use this in a powershell script? Or if this is not the correct document please refer the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

***I tried the steps below to call the Microsoft Purview Rest API to create and list entities from Data Catalog with Powershell:-***

***I added my service principal Collection admins, Data source admins and Data curators role like below:-***

[image]

[image]

[image]

Added **API permissions to the app to access Azure Purview scope** like below:-

[image]

I ran the Powershell code below to create the entity in Purview collection with storage account FQDN passed in the body like below:-

> I used the API to create entities from this MS document -
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/purview/catalogdataplane/entity/create-or-update-entities?tabs=HTTP

```
$AppId="<client-id>"
$AppSecret="<client-secret>"
$TokenURI="https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-id>/oauth2/token"
$Resource="https://purview.azure.net"


$BodyRequest="grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=$AppId&client_secret=$AppSecret&resource=$Resource"

$AccessToken=Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $TokenURI `
-Body $BodyRequest -ContentType  'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

$RequestURI="

https://<purviewaccount-name>.purview.azure.com/catalog/api/collections/<collection-name>/entity?api-version=2022-03-01-preview"

$body = @"
{
  "referredEntities": {},
  "entity": {
    "typeName": "azure_storage_account",
    "attributes": {
      "name": "exampleaccount",
      "qualifiedName": "https://exampleaccount.core.windows.net"
    }
  }
}
"@

$Headers=@{} 

$Headers.Add("Authorization","Bearer " + $AccessToken.access_token) 
  
$Result = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $RequestURI -Headers $Headers -Method POST -Body $body -Verbose -ContentType 'application/json')


Write-Host $Result
```

**Output:-**

Asset with Storage account got created in Purview collections like below:-

**Console:-**

[image]

**Portal:-**

[image]

> ***I used the below API from this MS document link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/purview/catalogdataplane/entity/get-by-unique-attributes?tabs=HTTP
> to call the Entity via its storage account FQDN with Powershell code
> :-***

**API-**

```http
GET https://siliconpurview.purview.azure.com/catalog/api/atlas/v2/entity/uniqueAttribute/type/azure_storage_account?minExtInfo=false&ignoreRelationships=true&attr:qualifiedName=https://exampleaccount.core.windows.net
```

**Powershell code:-**

```
$AppId="<client-id>"
$AppSecret="<client-secret>"
$TokenURI="https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-id>/oauth2/token"
$Resource="https://purview.azure.net"


$BodyRequest="grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=$AppId&client_secret=$AppSecret&resource=$Resource"

$AccessToken=Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $TokenURI `
-Body $BodyRequest -ContentType  'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

$RequestURI="https://<Purview-account-name>.purview.azure.com/catalog/api/atlas/v2/entity/uniqueAttribute/type/azure_storage_account?minExtInfo=false&ignoreRelationships=true&attr:qualifiedName=https://exampleaccount.core.windows.net"


$Headers=@{} 

$Headers.Add("Authorization","Bearer " + $AccessToken.access_token) 
  
$Result = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $RequestURI -Headers $Headers -Method GET )


Write-Host $Result
```

**Output:-**

**Console:-**

[image]

***Called the same API via Postman and got the complete body response like below:-***

[image]

> **Reference:-**
>
> [Entity - Create Or Update Entities - REST API (Azure Purview) |
> Microsoft
> Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/purview/catalogdataplane/entity/create-or-update-entities?tabs=HTTP)